# MS OLE DB is not provided in the current installation

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbuilder

I compiled a Powerbuilder 10.2 Program and released it to my users. it uses OLE DB Connection. Its working in any Programmer PCs except for our users. I think i might be missing a DLL or something to release in the Set. The problem is I dont know what I am missing.

Any help?

My throws sent this: MS OLE DB is not provided in the current installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need the **Microsoft SQL Server Native Client** that should be deployed on each user host.

Which version of SQL Server are you using ?

For SQL Server 2005, you can find it in the [Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24793) (look for **sqlncli**).

Comment: thx, ive done trial and error and put any dll from pb shared folder until the error went away. sql was pbole100.DLL but the error did not stop there also and just do "This program has stopped working". I tried putting every little DLL that was need with trial and error until it finally worked. thanks